# Installing java for mac

Tags: java, macos

I tried to download and install Java on my mac, but it doesn't work it says that the java is 10.6 version and I need a version for 10.9.5 macbook ... so any help please? any secure links to download java? 
I need it to write and test my codes. 
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Where did you download the package?

Comment: Java 10 ? Oh boy, Oracle decided to catch up on his agenda *in ONE step*. Seriously, you're more likely speaking of your OS X version. But in any case, you shouldn't be needing SO to install Java on a Mac, there are gazillions of tutorials on that matter on the web.

Answer (score 2):

Go to www.java.com and download Java. You may very well stop reading here.

Java 6 on (OS X) was being developed by Apple. Afterwards, they decided to do what should have been done in the first place: pursuit other goals, and let Oracle be the provider for 7 (as it happens on many other platforms).

Answer (score 1):

I am nearly certain that a java version comes with macs. If you issue the command java -version on the terminal you will see which version is available.

Also I think Java 1.7 does not work on mac osx 10.6

Comment: Not anymore. You have to download it from Oracle now.

Comment: Correct, 1.7 won't install on OS X 10.6. Come to think about it, I think one customer managed to do it somehow, and oh the hilarity that ensued afterwards, trying to figure out over the phone what happened...ended up in a GoToMeeting session.

Answer (score 0):

See [Java for OS X 2014-001](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572).  This is the version of Java 1.6 for OS X 10.7/10.8/10.9.

Because Apple is trying to get out of the Java business you could also consiider obtaining Java from Oracle - [Download Java for Mac OS X](https://java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp). This is Java version 1.7.

Comment: Apple has already left the Java business. What they did here was to allow their old proprietary Java 6 to be installed on newer systems. They did not post Java version 7, which made quite a few people happy. As a Java developer, having had to deal in the past with this or that peculiar behavior of their JRE, I say good riddance.